# How to access variables defined in a differnt class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, variables

If I have a variable in one external action script, is it possible for me to access it in another external action script? Also, how would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many ways. I have no idea what you mean be 'external,' but if you are talking about two classes, an instance of one of which adds, as a Child, an instance of another you can do one of the following.

If the Child wants to refer to a variable on the parent:

```
 var childvariable = parent.parentvariable
```

or

```
 var childvariable = MovieClip(parent).parentvariable
```

note that the parent variable should be declared as a `public var` in the parent class if the parent is in a different 'package' than the child.

If the parent wants to refer to a variable on the Child:

```
 Child.childvariable = something
```

or

```
 var newvariable = Child.childvariable
```

You can refer to a variable on a class (instead of an instance of a class) by first declaring the variable as a static var or static const and the referring to as:
     Classname.variable

There are other ways to refer to variables on sibling instances. Maybe you could ask a more specific question.

Comment: I have one variable in my X class named speed. I want to be able to access that variable in my Y class and be able to modify it and change it. They are in different action script files.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. And what is the relationship between those files? Child-parent? Sibling? Distant cousins? Are the classes instantiated? If so how?

Comment: Can you explain Child-Parent? I am not sure I understand that.

Comment: An object that instantiates another object is THAT object's parent. If A instantiates B, then A is the parent of B; B is a child of A. In order for a display object to become visible, in the Flash/Actionscript system, it must first be added to the 'display list' by it's parent, using the addChild() method.  Your original question is pretty advanced for someone who still has to learn some OOP basics. Maybe a good book, like 'Essential Actionscript 3.0’ might help?